# How to solve VBA type error when defining variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get VBA to do some data entry for me. I type the data in one sheet, and then it copies it into the correct row and columns in the other sheet. However, I keep getting an error that the type is incorrect in the following line:

```
r = Application.Match(row, ShEnter.Range("CH10:CH165"), 0)
```

What's going on here? Sorry, I'm very new to VBA. Thanks in advance for any help!

Full code:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub EnterData()
    
    'Dimension variables and declare data types
    Dim column1 As Long, column2 As String, column3 As Long, column4 As String, column5 As Long, column6 As Long, row As Long
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As String, c3 As Long, c4 As String, c5 As Long, c6 As Long, r As Long
    
    'Stop macro if cells are empty
    If ActiveSheet.Range("D8,D9, D13, D14, D15, D16, D17, D18").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
     
    'Save values in entry cells to variable columns
    column1 = ActiveSheet.Range("D13").Value
    column2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D14").Value
    column3 = ActiveSheet.Range("D15").Value
    column4 = ActiveSheet.Range("D16").Value
    column5 = ActiveSheet.Range("D17").Value
    column6 = ActiveSheet.Range("D18").Value
     
    'Save value in cell D10 to variable row
    row = ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value
    
    'Find relative position of value in cell C16 in cell range CH10:CH165 and save to variable r
    r = Application.Match(row, ShEnter.Range("CH10:CH165"), 0)
    
     
    'Find relative position of value in cell C15 in cell range B1:H1 and save to variable c
    c1 = Application.Match(column1, Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1:BW1"), 0)
     'Save value to table using coordinates
    Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1").Offset(r, c1).Value = Worksheets("ShEnter").Range("J17").Value

'Repeat for column2
c2 = Application.Match(column2, Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1:BW1"), 0)
Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1").Offset(r, c2).Value = Worksheets("ShEnter").Range("J18").Value

'Repeat for column3
c3 = Application.Match(column3, Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1:BW1"), 0)
Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1").Offset(r, c3).Value = Worksheets("ShEnter").Range("J19").Value

'Repeat for column4
c4 = Application.Match(column4, Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1:BW1"), 0)
Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1").Offset(r, c4).Value = Worksheets("ShEnter").Range("J20").Value

'Repeat for column5
c5 = Application.Match(column5, Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1:BW1"), 0)
Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1").Offset(r, c4).Value = Worksheets("ShEnter").Range("J20").Value

'Repeat for column6
c4 = Application.Match(column4, Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1:BW1"), 0)
Worksheets("ShData").Range("A1").Offset(r, c4).Value = Worksheets("ShEnter").Range("J20").Value
  
'Stop macro
End Sub
```

Comment: `r` has to be of variant type to be able to hold also error values in case of non findings (findings can be detected now via `If Not IsError(r) Then` or `If IsNumeric(r) Then`)

Comment: And weird fact but according to the documentation the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match#return-value) returns a `Double` not a `Long`.

Comment: Considering voting up just for having `Option Explicit` at the top especially when coupled with _I'm very new to VBA._  :)